# Last resort/catch-all/fallback template overload

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

As is evident in a question I asked previously,
[Overload resolution, templates and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405921/overload-resolution-templates-and-inheritance/28406090?noredirect=1#comment45149377_28406090), a template overload will be chosen before an overload which requires derived-to-base conversion.

However, is there a way to provide a fallback overload which is only selected as an absolute last resort if there is nothing else that matches? In this particular case `enable_if` could be used but that would not be extensible, unfortunately.

Like this:

```
// My library has this and has no knowledge of the possible overloads of foo
template<typename T>
void foo(const T &) { /* Do something */ }

// The user of the library provides this:
void foo(const UserBaseType &) { /* Do something */ }

// User calls foo with object derived from UserBaseType:
foo(UserDerivedType());
```

In this case, I want the UserBaseType overload to be called, not the template overload.

Comment: But here template version is matched, so it is not absolute last resort.

Comment: @ForEveR That's the point of the question - how to make it *be* the last resort.

Comment: Indeed, it is not an absolute last resort. Is there any way to simulate something like it?

Comment: Raymond Chen famously asks the question: "what if two (applications/libraries/...) tried this?" You cannot be lower then anyone else because then somebody else could also be lower than you which is logically impossible.

Comment: I of course place this function in a namespace that doesn't collide with the another library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're willing to require your users to provide their customization points via [Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), you can accomplish this with the proverbial additional layer of indirection. First, it is possible to determine if ADL for a given name succeeds by providing the worst possible fallback and determining if name lookup selects it[*]:

```
namespace detail {
  // Simple trait that computes the inverse of std::is_same
  template <typename, typename>
  struct is_different : std::true_type {};
  template <typename T>
  struct is_different<T, T> : std::false_type {};

  // The ellipsis conversion is worse than any other
  // conversion, so overload resolution will choose
  // this declaration of foo only if there is no
  // result from ADL.
  struct tag;
  tag foo(...);

  // Trait that determines if ADL for foo(T) succeeds.
  template <typename T>
  using has_adl_foo =
    is_different<tag,decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()))>;
}
```

Since the ellipsis conversion is strictly worse than either a standard or user-defined conversion sequence per [over.ics.rank]/2, any reasonable customization of `foo` provided by the library user will be a better match.

You then need some machinery to dispatch between your fallback implementation and a user-provided customization on the basis of the `has_adl_foo` trait:

```
namespace detail {
  // Fallback, used only if ADL fails.
  template <typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<!has_adl_foo<T>::value>::type
  impl(T&&) {
    std::cout << "Fallback\n";
  }

  // Dispatch to foo found by ADL.
  template <typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<has_adl_foo<T>::value,
    decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()))
  >::type
  impl(T&& t) {
    return foo(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
}

template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t) ->
  decltype(detail::impl(std::forward<T>(t))) {
    return detail::impl(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Users can then provide their customizations fairly simply - simple compared to specializing templates in your library namespace, anyway - by declaring `foo` overloads in the namespace of their class declarations where ADL can find them ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2eab8717786a6d8c)):

```
struct UserType {};
struct DerivedUserType : UserType {};

void foo(const UserType&) {
  std::cout << "User extension\n";
}
```

---

<sub>[*]: ADL Detection technique adapted from [@T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744589/what-is-a-proper-way-to-implement-is-swappable-to-test-for-the-swappable-concept/26852703#26852703) to [What is a proper way to implement `is_swappable` to test for the Swappable concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744589/what-is-a-proper-way-to-implement-is-swappable-to-test-for-the-swappable-concept).</sub>

Comment: Couldn't the definition of `is_different` just be `template <typename A, typename B> struct is_different : std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_same<A, B>::value> {};`?

Comment: @refi64 Yes, it could. I have no idea what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

The only parameter guaranteed to have lower precedence than anything else are C-style variadics: `...`, and that is certainly not what you'd want (or even be able to) use.

I am afraid there is nothing to provide where the only user-side customisation would be providing an overload. If you can tolerate a little bit higher burden on the user, though, you could make it work with a trait class:

```
template <class T>
struct HasCustomFoo : std::false_type
{};

template <class T, class Sfinae = typename std::enable_if<!HasCustomFoo<T>::value>::type>
void foo(const T &) { /* Do something generic */}
```

Then, the user of the library must specialise `HasCustomFoo` for all applicable classes:

```
template <>
struct HasCustomFoo<UserBaseType> : std::true_type
{};

template <>
struct HasCustomFoo<UserDerivedType> : std::true_type
{};

void foo(const UserBaseType &) { /* Do something user-specific */ }

foo(UserDerivedType()); // This now calls the user-specific function
```

It's not fully automatic, but at least the solution is in the user's hands and the library can remain generic.

Comment: How is this less work than forcing the user to provide separate overloads for each derived class?

I provide `template<typename T> void foo(const T &) { ... }` and user provides `void foo(const Base &) { ... }`, `void foo(const Derived &) { ... }`. Seems like less code than your example.

Comment: @EmilEriksson They don't have to provide the body. I'm not saying it's perfect, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: It's a bit unsatisfactory but that's not your fault, it's the best I can come up with as well. Accepting :)

Comment: @EmilEriksson You might want to hold off the accept, at least for a few days. Maybe some of the real template gurus has something better.